# pdf embedded in emacs?

Tags: pdf, emacs, docview

I would like to ask if anybody knows of a possibility to render pdf file inside emacs. I noticed with w3m browsing a web page with a link to pdf it actually open with doc view it in another buffer (as you can see). How can I do it with other packages ?

[image: Imgur]

Comment: For anyone interested in building `ghostscript` from scratch, here is the link to the sources:  http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/  The archive named `ghostscript-9.14.tar.gz` is **bad** and I'll file a report with the developers this evening.  The archive `ghostscript-9.14.tar.bz2` is **good** and can be extracted with a variety of tools, including, but not limited to `The Unarchiver.app` on OSX 10.6.8.  Same procedure as usual -- e.g., `./configure --prefix=/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs` and then `make` and then `sudo make install`.  The archive has all the dependencies!  :)

Comment: For anyone who builds `ghostscript` from scratch and does not want to add the location to the `$PATH`, here is the way to specify an absolute path:  `(setq doc-view-ghostscript-program "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/bin/gs")` -- just adjust the path to wherever `gs` is located.  **NOTE**:  There are plenty of other methods available for installation (however, I like complete control), e.g., homebrew, macports, other binaries on the net that can be found with Google, e.g., `XQuartz-2.7.6.dmg` for OSX; Ghostscript-9.07.pkg.zip for OSX; and another link here:  http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/

Answer (score 6):

As long as you have Ghostscript installed, you can view PDF files in Emacs just by opening them as any other file, with <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd>.  `doc-view-mode` should start automatically, but if it doesn't, you can do it manually with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `doc-view-mode`.  More information is available [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Document-View.html).

Comment: Yes. I 've just intalled ghostscript for another reason through brew and as a *collateral* effect I noticed this on emacs.

Comment: PDF viewing through DocView mode converts the PDF to images and displays the images. As a result you don't get exact fidelity. Embedded hyperlinks, for instance, do not work.

Answer (score 1):

You may try pdf-tools for emacs.
[pdf-tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools)
Just install it using M-x package-install-file RET pdf-tools

Comment: Well, not under Windows, because it won't compile without quite some effort, see the descriptions on the website you cited.